# Examples of various XML definitions

Tags: xml, grammar, context-free-grammar, w3c

In reading the [XML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Comment), it mentions the following definitions:

```
Names and Tokens
[4]     NameStartChar      ::=      ":" | [A-Z] | "_" | [a-z] | [#xC0-#xD6] | [#xD8-#xF6] | [#xF8-#x2FF] | [#x370-#x37D] | [#x37F-#x1FFF] | [#x200C-#x200D] | [#x2070-#x218F] | [#x2C00-#x2FEF] | [#x3001-#xD7FF] | [#xF900-#xFDCF] | [#xFDF0-#xFFFD] | [#x10000-#xEFFFF]
[4a]    NameChar           ::=      NameStartChar | "-" | "." | [0-9] | #xB7 | [#x0300-#x036F] | [#x203F-#x2040]
[5]     Name               ::=      NameStartChar (NameChar)*

Literals
[9]     EntityValue        ::=      '"' ([^%&"] | PEReference | Reference)* '"' |  "'" ([^%&'] | PEReference | Reference)* "'"
[10]    AttValue           ::=      '"' ([^<&"] | Reference)* '"'|  "'" ([^<&'] | Reference)* "'"
[11]    SystemLiteral      ::=      ('"' [^"]* '"') | ("'" [^']* "'")
[12]    PubidLiteral       ::=      '"' PubidChar* '"' | "'" (PubidChar - "'")* "'"
[13]    PubidChar          ::=      #x20 | #xD | #xA | [a-zA-Z0-9] | [-'()+,./:=?;!*#@$_%]
```

What would be an example of a Name vs. an Entity vs an Attribute vs a SystemLiteral vs a Pubid (?)

For example in the below:

```
<Item id="123">Hello<Item/>
```

Is `Item` the Name or the EntityValue? And I would assume that `123` or `"123"` would be the Att(ribute)Value. Are those both correct? What would be examples of the others?

From the spec it says:

> Literal data is any quoted string not containing the quotation mark used as a delimiter for that string. Literals are used for specifying the content of internal entities (EntityValue), the values of attributes (AttValue), and external identifiers (SystemLiteral).

So from that I would think `Item` would be the **EntityValue**, `123` would be the **AttrValue**: what would be examples of a PubID and SystemLiteral then? Finally, why doesn't the `EntityValue` exclude the `<` and `>` chars?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Your XML example is parsed as follows:**

`<Item id="123">Hello<Item/>` is an [element](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#dt-element):

- `<Item id="123">` is an [STag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-STag):

  - `Item` is a [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name).
  - `id="123"` is an [Attribute](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Attribute):

    - `id` is a [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name);
    - `"123"` is an [AttValue](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-AttValue), which is the only *Literal* in this example.
- `Hello` is [content](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-content), which is [CharData](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-CharData) in this example.
- `<Item/>` is an [ETag](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-ETag):

  - `Item` is a [Name](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-Name).

**There are none of the following constructs in your example:**

- [EntityValue](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-EntityValue)
   Example: `"2020"` in `<!ENTITY year "2020">`
- [PubidLiteral](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-PubidLiteral)
   Example: `"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"` in `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">`  )
- [SystemLiteral](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#NT-SystemLiteral)
   Example: `"../img/logo.gif"` in `<!ENTITY logo SYSTEM "../img/logo.gif" NDATA gif >`

See section [4.2 Entity Declarations](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-entity-decl) for more context on how `EntityValue`, `PubidLiteral`, and `SystemLiteral` are used.

Comment: thanks for these answers. By the way, would you recommend any place to learn more about the XML standard and such other than the official w3c page? I find that pretty tough going...Especially how the concepts are often defined after the initial language syntax (though I'm probably below the average reader of the w3c standard...).

Comment: You seem to know more than a beginner (if not, search for "xml tutorials") and probably could do well continuing pressing on with your work and diving into the spec tactically, or  reading answers / asking questions here, regarding specific areas as needed.